# Extract date from URL link / random string

Tags: r

I would like to extract dates from a column of URL links (5,000 rows of raw data).
Sample of the URL include:

- http://en/Pages/Introduction-More_Details-20191103.com
- http://en/Pages/United-Kingdom-Page1-EU-20190502.com
- http://en/Pages/France-2019-Description-20190612.com
- http://en/Pages/telephone-in-the-UK-and-USA-190405.com

Is there any R code that can learn the pattern and extract the date to another column?

Thank you.

The different length of text can be a problem...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At least from your sample it looks like the dates are the only numbers and they always follow a `-`. You could catch them with regex:

```
urls <- c('http://en/Pages/Introduction-More_Details-20191103.com',
          'http://en/Pages/United-Kingdom-EU-20190502.com', 
          'http://en/Pages/France-20190612.com',
          'http://en/Pages/telephone-in-the-UK-and-USA-190405.com')

gsub('(.*)-(\\d{6,8})(.*)', '\\2', urls)
#[1] "20191103" "20190502" "20190612" "190405"
```

Or

```
gsub('(.*)-(\\d{6,8})(\\.com)', '\\2', urls)
```

Then you save that to a new column. Obviously, how easy it is to pick up all the urls depends on how many different formats you have.

Comment: Hi. Thanks for your comment. Apologies that my question looks messy just now. I have edited my question. Also, I have checked to see if there are numbers other than the dates. Apparently, lots of the URL links also contains some number which are not the date. Any suggestions?

Comment: You could specify that the number needs to be between 6 and 8. I updated the answer. In order to capture everything you need to take into account all the numeric possibilities. There is no magical way to capture just the dates. In the answer above it says a number between 6 and 8 digits that follows a `-`

Comment: @LyzandeR perhaps use the `.com` to orient the match rather than the `-`, assuming the dates are always just prior to `.com`?

Comment: I was thinking about it @gersht . It really depends on what the OP wants / what kind of patterns he has. But I agree, .com also makes sense.

Comment: Hi, I have tried the code but only 1 line is shown as output. URLs I currently have on Excel are as follows:

http://news.global.abc/en/news/Pages/photo-group-20190610.aspx
http://news.global.abc/en/news/Pages/it-is-the-worst-time-of-my-job-hong-kingdom-20190612.aspx
http://news.global.abc/en/news/Pages/discount-offers-camera-conversion-between-abc-keys-06132019.aspx
http://news.global.abc/en/news/Pages/discount-offers-now-between-abc-door-061319.aspx
http://news.global.abc/en/news/Pages/food-group-market.aspx

Some links don't contain any dates.
@LyzandeR